# I have created a function that is supposed to flip the text horizontally in php but something isn't working

Tags: php, text, flip

I am trying to replace every character from a string with it's opposite but the following code is replacing only chars with chars but it does not recognize ASCII codes.

Can you please help me? Can you please tell me why? I have tried using the chr function but it doesn't work. It shows me nothing.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
function flip($v)
{
    $flipped="";
    $size=strlen($v);

    $array=str_split($v,1); 

    for($i=0;$i<$size;$i++)
    {
        switch($array[$i])
            {
                case 'a': $flipped .= '\u0250';
                            break;
                case 'b' : $flipped .='q';
                            break;
                case 'c' : $flipped .='\u0254';
                            break;
                case 'd': $flipped .='p';
                            break;
                case 'e': $flipped .='\u01DD';
                            break;
                case 'f': $flipped .='\u025F';
                            break;
                case 'g' : $flipped .='\u0183';
                            break;
                case 'h': $flipped .='\u0265';
                            break;
                case 'i' : $flipped .='\u0131';
                            break;
                case 'j' : $flipped .='\u027E';
                            break;
                case 'k' : $flipped .='\u029E';
                            break;
                case 'l' : $flipped .='\u0283';
                            break;
                case 'm' : $flipped .='\u026F';
                            break;
                case 'n' : $flipped .='u';
                            break;
                case 'r' : $flipped .='\u0279';
                            break;
                case 't' : $flipped .='\u0287';
                            break;
                case 'v' : $flipped .='\u028C';
                            break;
                case 'w' : $flipped .='\u028D';
                            break;
                case 'y' : $flipped .='\u028E';
                            break;
                case '.' : $flipped .='\u02D9';
                            break;
                case '[' : $flipped .=']';
                            break;
                case '(' : $flipped .=')';
                            break;
                case '{' : $flipped .='}';
                            break;
                case '?' : $flipped .='\u00BF';
                            break;
                case '!' : $flipped .='\u00A1';
                            break;
                case "\'" : $flipped .=',';
                            break;
                case '<' : $flipped .='>';
                            break;
                case '_' : $flipped .='\u203E';
                            break;
                case ';' : $flipped .='\u061B';
                            break;
                case '\u203F' : $flipped .='\u2040';
                            break;
                case '\u2045' : $flipped .='\u2046';
                            break;
                case '\u2234' : $flipped .='\u2235';
                            break;
                case '\r' : $flipped .='\n';
                            break;
                case ' ' : $flipped .=''; 
                            break;  
            }
    }

return $flipped;
}

echo flip("abcdefghijklmnopqrst");
?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Parts of your function are missing.

Comment: @Louis H. scroll down the php code. Or tell me what parts?

Comment: It didn't show the function header before. Seems to be okay now. (Probably some faulty formatting).

Comment: if I use chr the output is blank and otherwise it shoes me the code I want to add... for example it shows me '\u027E'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change them to htmlentity like,

```
case 'a': $flipped .= '&#592;';
break;
case 'b' : $flipped .='q';
break;
case 'c' : $flipped .='&#596;';
break; etc....
```

Comment: you are welcome. in case you need help with the conversion, here's a [link](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/254/index.htm) which can be helpful.

Comment: can you tell me please where can I find the table with the codes? because I also need the codes for flipping numbers and I want to complete my function. Thanks again !